# Tracing through a recursive function

Tags: java, function, recursion

For the following code segment, I am having trouble tracing through it (which I need to be able to do for my upcoming test.

```
public int question(int x, int y)
{
    if (x ==y)
        return 0;
    else
        return question(x-1, y) + 1;
}
```

I am also confused as to what the + 1 is doing. What is 1 being added on to. I know the result is five, but I need to be able to better understand the concept. Thanks for your help.

Comment: The initial values are kind of important... or otherwise it's hard to say the answer is 5

Comment: I do know what recursion is, I'm just having difficulty understanding how to trace through it

Comment: Just put a println statement in there and watch the magic unfold.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include that x = 8, and y = 3.

Comment: That code's not going to work too well if you call with, say, `question(2,3)`...

Comment: Basically, if the result is 5, then you have to find the call that makes this code run 5 times because 1 is being added upon each iteration. There is no way to determine the exact input though, all that can be deduced from this code is that X is 5 larger than Y

Comment: The most common cause of stack overflow is recursion. Need More? :)

Answer (score 5):

Basically:

`question(8,3)` will return `question(7,3) + 1`

`question(7,3)` will return `question(6,3) + 1`

`question(6,3)` will return `question(5,3) + 1`

`question(5,3)` will return `question(4,3) + 1`

`question(4,3)` will return `question(3,3) + 1`

and `question(3,3)` is 0.

It should be obvious that the result of `question(8,3)` is 5 by simple substitution. It should be noted that if `x < y` then you might get a stack overflow as `x` keeps decrementing and will possibly never get to `x == y`.

Comment: Thanks for the excellent explanation, I did not write the code my professor did on the test.

Answer (score 1):

the 1 is being added onto the return from the function every time the function recurses 1 is added onto the return of int

```
public int question(int x, int y)
{
    if (x ==y)
        return 0;
    else
        return question(x-1, y) + 1;
}
```

say you call

```
int result = question(5,0);
```

since your general case calls

```
 return question(x-1, y) + 1;
```

the + 1 is going to recurse until you hit the base case of

```
 if (x ==y)
        return 0;
```

giving you +1 +1 +1 +1 +1 +0

until x = 0 and y = 0

Answer (score 1):

You can always add a couple prints to the method to better understand what it is doing:

```
static int question(int x, int y) {
    if (x ==y) {
        System.out.println(x + " == " + y);
        System.out.println("return 0");
        return 0;
    } else {
        System.out.println(x + " != " + y);
        System.out.println("call question(" + (x - 1) + ", " + y + ")");
        int result = question(x - 1, y);
        System.out.println("return " + result + " + 1");
        return result + 1;
    }
}
```

Then call it. For example:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    System.out.println(question(8, 3));
}
```

Output:

```
8 != 3
call question(7, 3)
7 != 3
call question(6, 3)
6 != 3
call question(5, 3)
5 != 3
call question(4, 3)
4 != 3
call question(3, 3)
3 == 3
return 0
return 0 + 1
return 1 + 1
return 2 + 1
return 3 + 1
return 4 + 1
5
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice and the output as well!

Answer (score 0):

In order to understand recursion, try to write function in a mathematical way. I will first demonstrate this with the classic factorial, then explain you the example you gave.

Let `fact(n)` be `n!`. The recursive definition of factorial is:

`fact(n) = 1, if n <= 1`

`fact(n) = n * fact(n - 1)`

Note that we have 2 cases: a base case, which is a simple case that can be calculated directly, and a step case, which requires the value of a recursive call. Note that in order for the recursion to work, the recursive function call should be simpler, in order to move towards the step case. This can be implemented easily in Java:

```
public int factorial(int n)
{
    if (n < 2)
        return 1;
    else
        return n*factorial(n-1);
}
```

Returning to your function, you have to do the same process backwards. We can easily identify the 2 base cases as the branches of if:

`Base case: question(x, y) = 0, if x = y`
`Step case: question(x, y) = question(x - 1, y) + 1, otherwise`

It can be noticed that at each recursive call you subtract 1 from x and add 1 to the result. Let's unroll the recursion for `question(8, 3)`:

```
question(8, 3) = question(7, 3) + 1 // You are in the step case
question(7, 3) = question(6, 3) + 1
question(6, 3) = question(5, 3) + 1
question(5, 3) = question(4, 3) + 1
question(4, 3) = question(3, 3) + 1
question(3, 3) = 0 // The base case
```

Now, if you replace the value of `question(3, 3)` in the value of `question(4, 3)` and do the same upwards, you find out that the result is 8.

There is no straight way to do this, but you can notice that the first parameter is decreasing by 1 and each time this is done, the result increases by 1, until the parameters are equal. Using some intuition, you may notice that this basically computes x - y.

Note that this method requires x >= y, otherwise it will crash.